# How to convert date mdy format to ymd format?

Tags: php, date

Hi all i want to convert mdy format of date to ymd format

```
$todate = '03-31-2016;
```

I am using this code to convert it

```
$todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todate));
```

This code gives me output

```
1969-12-31
```

so whats the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: its not null i am getting $todate = '03-31-2016;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$date = '03-31-2016;
$todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: I have do the same thng

Comment: No you use $todate in strtotime() function instead of $date

Comment: i had update the code see edit

Comment: just check it here wwith this code here - http://phpfiddle.org/
$todate = "03-31-2016";
 $todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todate));
 echo $todate;